# C#: Create Inherited DbContext, do we have to conduct Dependency Injection again?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I created an inherited DbContext Class from another DbContext. It performs custom items, such as logs user information before SaveChanges, for certain tables.

Is it necessary to conduct Dependency Injection Again in the Startup.cs?

Otherwise, we receive error below.

> Error: No service for type 'IPTS.PropertyManagement.Infrastructure.Repositories.CustomPropertyContext' has been registered.

This second pair code line resolves issue, just curious if any way to avoid having to reinject again, or is it Necessary?

```
services.AddDbContext<PropertyContext>(options =>
   options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("PMConnection")));
services.AddScoped<DbContext, PropertyContext>();

services.AddDbContext<CustomPropertyContext>(options =>
   options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("PMConnection")));
services.AddScoped<DbContext, CustomPropertyContext>();
```

**Reference Custom Class:**

```
public class CustomPropertyContext : PropertyContext
{
    private int _user;

    public CustomPropertyContext()
    {
    }

    public CustomPropertyContext(UserResolverService userService)
    {
        _user = userService.GetUser();
    }

    public void ApplyCreatedBy()
    {
        var modifiedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries<ICreatedBy>().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added);
        foreach (var entity in modifiedEntities)
        {
            entity.Property("CreatedBy").CurrentValue = _user;
        }
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        ApplyCreatedBy();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

This is for a property application system by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This second pair code line resolves issue, just curious if any way to avoid having to reinject again, or is it Necessary?

Yes the second pair is necessary so DI know all types need to be injected as you said in comment below your question sometimes you inject `PropertyContext` and some othe times you use `CustomPropertyContext`. So it is the right thing to do but you can simplify the code like below:

```
var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("PMConnection");
services.AddDbContext<PropertyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
services.AddDbContext<CustomPropertyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

As you see I remove lines that inject `DbContext` base class because you said that you are not injecting `DbContext` base class but a specific derived class either `PropertyContext` or `CustomPropertyContext`. Also you need to know that by registering many times the same type (here `DbContext`) the last registration will always win when you ask for an instance of `DbContext`. So based on the code below:

```
services.AddScoped<DbContext, PropertyContext>();
services.AddScoped<DbContext, CustomPropertyContext>();
```

The last registration wins and you'll always get an instance of `CustomPropertyContext` when you ask for a single instance of `DbContext`.